# How do I update 1.4.1 website

Tags: magento-upgrade

I would like to **upgrade** to the Magento's **latest version** and latest version of **theme**. I know very about coding. What do I need to do?

Comment: which version you want to upgrade? and also which theme upgrade ?

Answer (score 0):

for upgrade to latest version of magento
you simple need to follow below step
 1. Take database and file backup
 2. Copy latest magento file and folder
 3. upload to root directory
 4. delete cache,report,session from var folder
 5. open site